# XSS injection via addressbar

Tags: javascript, security, url, xss, code-injection

I am testing for XSS, I add some JavaScript code in the URL and suddenly all the pictures and style of the page disappear, displaying just the text content, and the injected JavaScript command even doesn't get executed, does what happens mean my code is vulnerable to this type of XSS?

The URL is:

```
http://localhost/index.php/<script>alert('hacked');</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This has nothing to do with XSS (that the script is not being executed is a good clue to that!).

What is means is that `http://localhost/index.php/<script>alert('hacked');</` is a different "directory" to `http://localhost/index.php/` or `http://localhost/`.

You have relative URLs in your document and they don't start with a `/` so they are relative to the URL of the page.

Since you are accessing the page from a URL that points to a different directory, the links have broken.

Answer (score -1):

For a better understanding about CrossSite Scripting and how to replicate and prevent it, I recommend you the [**OWASP site**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), which also includes documentation about other common web vulnerabilities.

> The URL is: `http://localhost/index.php/script alert('hacked');script`

Also, is not helpful to post an URL pointing to your **localhost**, since that site is in your machine and not on the internet, so we cannot access it and test it. If that same site is also published on the internet, post it with its public IP or its domain.

> I dropped the <> of the script tag here as it is filtered

To post source code of any language in a question, format it with the `Code` format (the brackets button, in the format toolbar).

```
<script>Example of source code with script tag</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help, sorry I still have not this website running yet

Comment: It's not a good idea to post a link to a website containing any vulnerability anywhere public, including StackOverflow. Just think what any attacker will do with this information. It is better to discuss this in concept only, so that it is self contained to SO as much as possible rather than linking to external sites for examples (where the bug will also disappear once fixed by the OP).